# Unescaping dynamic segment in link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find the best way to unescape a parameter in my URL's via the link_to helper.

I want to unescape it because of Mailchimp's merge tags (ex: *|FIRST_NAME|*) so that I can that in the url. However when I add it like that it gets encoded and returns:

http://localhost:3000/13?f_name=%2A%7CFIRST_NAME%7C%2A

whilst the result I want is:

http://localhost:3000/13?f_name=*|FIRST_NAME|*

the current code is quite simple:

```
link_to('lorem', u_path(u.id, f_name: "*|FIRST_NAME|*"))
```

Comment: link_to('lorem', u_path(u.id, f_name: "*|FIRST_NAME|*").html_safe)

Comment: @dwilkins Have you tried that? `html_safe` works with HTML encoding, the %-stuff is URL encoding and is done by the URL helper.